# SQLDataReader and CommandBehaviour.CloseConnection

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

I have a generic class called "db" which talks directly to the database.  And have a method called "ExecuteDataReader" as below:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteDataReader(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenConnection();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;              

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                return dr;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utils.Debug(string.Format("Err in {0}.{1} : {2}\nSQL : {3}", this.GetType(), "ExecuteDataReader", ex.Message, cmd.CommandText));
                return null;
            }            
        }
```

Then, I execute the resource intensive query which loops through 10000 parent records and 20000 child records to update in the database.  And then I got the following error:

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

To solve these problems, I have to call dr.Close() explicitly after the execution.

```
static void ProcessAssessmentCriteria(string UnitReference)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRACKING.DBTool_GetUniqueAssessmentCriteriaByUnitReference");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitReference", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = UnitReference;

            SqlDataReader dr = db.ExecuteDataReader(cmd);

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {                    
                    ProcessDetailAssessmentCriteria(UnitReference, dr["AssessmentRefNumber"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("---------------");
                }
            }

            dr.Close();
        }
```

Due to my knowledge, the CommandBehaviour.CloseConnection() automatically close the connection.  But it seems that it does not close now.  Could you please enlighten me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CommandBehavior.CloseConnection from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx)

> When the command is executed, the associated Connection object is
>   closed **when the associated DataReader object is closed**.

So only when you close the DataReader the connection is Closed.

Comment: oh yeah.  I misunderstood it. :)